# APK signed by ADO pipeline fails to install with "App not installed" error possibly due to signing issues

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm new to xamarin and mobile development and am having a really hard time deploying my app to an actual device. Every time I try to install on anything but an emulator, I get an `App not installed` error. I've spent a lot of time going over similar questions/issues online, but none of them have helped or at least I haven't been able to apply them to my situation successfully since the vast majority seem to apply to working in android studio and building the apk manually.

I'm using xamarin.forms in VS 2019, and then am using an ADO pipeline to build and sign the .apk file. From my pipeline's perspective, things seem to be working okay. The Signing step supposedly signs and verifies successfully, but trying to debug the .apk file in android studio I get the following errors:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
```

and `APK signature verification failed.`

Running the command `apksigner verify --print-certs <myapkfile>.apk`, I get the following error:

```
DOES NOT VERIFY
ERROR: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

I'm unsure why my signed apk still fails with those errors and based off the [guide for signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/android-signing?view=azure-devops) I don't see anything I'm missing.

### Configuration

My Target android version is Android 10.0 (API Level 29) and the tasks in my ADO .yaml pipeline are configured as follows:

```
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*Droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    createAppPackage: true
    jdkOption: 'JDKVersion'
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
    apksign: true
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: OnDeck
    apksignerKeystoreFile: 'release.keystore'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: $(CredentialPassword)
    apksignerKeyPassword: $(CredentialPassword)
```

I feel like its got to be some really minor thing I'm missing, but I just cannot figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of installing the same version in mobile but build on a different system (cause different SHA1 key)

Solution:- Increase version number and try to install.

Comment: When you say increase the version, do you mean the target android version, the manifest version, or something in my yaml build? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your app version only.   versionCode and versionName